# Why isn't the money demand function called the real money balances demand function?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, money-supply

M=Money supply

P=Price

k= How much money people wish to hold for each dollar of income = exogenous.

Y = output

M/P= real money balances

Money demand function: (M/P)^d = kY

Why isn't the money demand function called the real money balances demand function?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! (M/P)^d = kY seems more like an equation (related to an equilibrium) than an f(x) = ... type function definition. Can you link to a source that claims this as the definition?

Comment: The source tis the lecture presentation from my previous uni

Comment: Then to resolve your question: it is very likely that the notes or their translation is imprecise.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot